# Facebook Login in jQuery Dialog - MVC 4 ActionResult in jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

Someone can suggest me what is the clean and proper way to render, what was a MVC 4 RedirectResult, in a jQuery Dialog?

I have a Facebook Plugin that return a "RedirectResult" so that during the login process the user is redirect on the facebook login page and then back to the website.
I would like to load the login page in a jQuery dialog so to not leave the website page.

In my controller I have:

```
    if (result.Result != null) return result.Result;

    return HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated ? new RedirectResult(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : "~/") : new RedirectResult(Url.LogOn(returnUrl));
```

**"result.Result" is a RedirectResult Type** and here I have the URL that contain the redirect.

Following the view with the jQuery Dialog where I would like to load the login facebook page:

```
   @using Nop.Web.Framework.UI
    @{
    Layout = "";
    Html.AddCssFileParts("./Plugins/ExternalAuth.Facebook/Content/facebookstyles.css");
    }

<fieldset class="facebook-login-block">
    <legend>@T("Plugins.ExternalAuth.Facebook.Login")</legend>

    <a href="#" class="facebook-btn" id="facebook-btn">&nbsp;</a>
</fieldset>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("a#facebook-btn").click(function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $('#dialog').dialog({
                      resizable: true,
                      height: 250,
                      width: 400,
                      modal: true,
                      open: function (event, ui) {
                          $('#dialog').load("@Url.RouteUrl("Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.Login", new { ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })");             
                      }
                  });


            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="dialog" style="display:none"></div>
```

This is the original call:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.Login", new { ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })" class="facebook-btn">
    &nbsp;</a>
```

I tried to move it in the load function but this have not produce any result.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found a possible solution by myself, I don't know if is this is the best and clean way, but works. Following the details.

I changed my controller to this:

```
        if (result.Result != null) // return result.Result;
        {
            RedirectResult RR = (RedirectResult)result.Result;
            return Content(RR.Url);
        }

        return HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated ? new RedirectResult(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : "~/") : new RedirectResult(Url.LogOn(returnUrl));
```

and my view to this:

```
<fieldset class="facebook-login-block">
    <legend>@T("Plugins.ExternalAuth.Facebook.Login")</legend>

    @*<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.Login", new { ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })" class="facebook-btn">
        &nbsp;</a>*@
    <a href="#" class="facebook-btn" id="facebook-btn">&nbsp;</a>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("a#facebook-btn").click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  async: false,
                  url: "@Url.RouteUrl("Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.Login", new { ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  error: function () { return true; },
                  success: function (data) {
                      var $dialog = $('#dialog')
                                      .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + data + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                                      .dialog({
                                      resizable: true,
                                      height: 250,
                                      width: 400,
                                      modal: true
                                      });

                      $dialog.dialog('open');
                  }
              });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog" style="display:none"></div>
```

Any other solutions are welcome.

Comment: My first approach was working just during the authentication process. Unfortunately I have discovered that facebook doesn't like iframe so I had to use window.open instead of jquery dialog. If someone else have a better solution, he is welcome to let me know.